# Inspecting elements and using XPATH to get the correct data python

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrape all coinID's [form this website](http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/).

When inpecting the element, the [ID's are seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9JTZ.png), however when copying with Xpath I get:

```
//*[@id="id-bitcoin"]
```

I'm planning on using this python code:

```
from lxml import html 
import requests 

page = requests.get('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

ID = tree.xpath('')

print ID
```

But I'm not sure what to look for in the element to plug into tree.xpath('')

I was hoping for something like

```
//span[@class="id"]/text()
```

I tried to printing the tree to understand the data better, but it's printing this `what's the syntax to see the data, something like tree.getdata() ?

Any info on how I can get these coin ID names would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: yes, can you give an example of what you want to extract?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are trying to get the `id`'s of `tr` tags. As id is an attribute of the tag, you can get it like this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

trs = tree.xpath('//table[@id="currencies-all"]/tbody/tr')

for tr in trs:
    print tr.attrib.get('id')
```

You shall get output like this:

```
id-bitcoin
id-ripple
id-litecoin
id-ethereum
id-dash
id-dogecoin
...
```

If you want to get the data from each row `tr`, you can find each `td` tag inside the `tr` and extract the text content.

```
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.findall('td')
    data = [td.text_content().strip() for td in tds]
    print data
```

Output:

```
['1', 'Bitcoin', 'BTC', '$ 6,815,160,833', '$ 452.70', '15,054,475', '$ 75,535,400', '-0.21 %', '5.19 %', '5.76 %']
...
```

You might need to cleanup the data.

Answer (score 3):

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
ID = tree.xpath('//img[@class="currency-logo"]/@alt')
print ID
```

output :

```
['Bitcoin', 'Ripple', 'Litecoin', 'Ethereum', 'Dash', 'Dogecoin', 'Peercoin', 'Stellar', 'BitShares', 'MaidSafeCoin', 'Nxt', 'Bytecoin', 'Namecoin', 'Monero', 'Factom', 'EmerCoin', 'GridCoin', 'NuShares', 'Rubycoin', 'NEM', 'MonaCoin', 'Clams', 'BlackCoin', 'YbCoin', 'Startcoin', 'Counterparty', 'Tether', 'BitcoinDark', 'Bitcrystals', 'Synereo', 'Global Currency Reserve', 'Mastercoin (Omni)', 'Novacoin', 'GetGems', 'MUSE', 'AmberCoin', 'PayCoin', 'VeriCoin', 'Rimbit', 'CasinoCoin', 'Primecoin', 'DigiByte', 'I0Coin', 'Storjcoin X', 'Megacoin', 'ShadowCash', 'NeuCoin', 'Mintcoin', 'VPNCoin', 'Quark', 'ReddCoin', 'SuperNET', 'WorldCoin', 'SolarCoin', 'GameCredits', 'FuelCoin', 'DNotes', 'NautilusCoin', 'BoostCoin', 'Vanillacoin', 'EarthCoin', 'DigitalNote', 'Infinitecoin', 'Scotcoin', 'Diamond', 'Gulden', 'Vertcoin', 'ARCHcoin', 'Crypti', 'Feathercoin', 'FedoraCoin', 'Applecoin', 'InstantDEX', 'Electronic Gulden', 'Auroracoin', 'Unobtanium', 'BilShares', 'Zetacoin', 'Digitalcoin', 'Anoncoin', 'FairCoin', 'CureCoin', 'I/O Coin', 'AsiaCoin', 'Obits', 'NetCoin', 'Swarm', 'SysCoin', 'MaxCoin', 'Virtacoin', 'UnionCoin', 'Flycoin', 'Riecoin', 'Crypto Bullion', 'Horizon', 'SpreadCoin', 'EuropeCoin', 'Siacoin', 'CloakCoin', 'LIQUID', 'BitBay', 'TileCoin', 'TEKcoin', 'ZcCoin', 'Jinn', 'Qora', 'TagCoin', 'HyperStake', 'Navajo', 'Aeon', 'CannabisCoin', 'Xaurum', 'DogeCoinDark', 'PotCoin', 'GoldCoin', 'jl777hodl', 'Bytecent', 'SmileyCoin', 'StabilityShares', 'HoboNickels', 'bitUSD', 'XCurrency', 'NXTventure', 'Burst', 'Orbitcoin', 'Zeitcoin', 'Devcoin', 'Quatloo', 'Tickets', 'Jumbucks', 'Cannacoin', 'Memorycoin', 'AudioCoin', 'CORE', 'TrustPlus', 'Viacoin', 'OrangeCoin', 'Woodcoin', 'Stealthcoin', 'BitSwift', 'Coinomat', 'Silkcoin', 'bitCNY', 'FlorinCoin', 'MazaCoin', 'Canada eCoin', 'Xiaomicoin', 'Cryptofund', 'Joincoin', 'Boolberry', 'GeoCoin', 'VootCoin', 'Qibuck', 'Mooncoin', 'Energycoin', 'SecureCoin', 'Node', 'WhiteCoin', 'OKCash', 'GroestlCoin', 'ArtByte', 'BitShares PTS', 'BitBean', 'Hyper', 'Capricoin', 'CoinoIndex', 'RedCoin', 'WildBeastBitcoin', 'SIBCoin', 'BitStone', 'Terracoin', 'Myriadcoin', 'CryptoEscudo', 'TransferCoin', 'RibbitRewards', 'Truckcoin', 'Expanse', 'Opal', 'OpenBTC', 'Blitz', 'MediterraneanCoin', 'LTBcoin', 'Magi', 'Cryptonite', 'DigiCube', 'Bitmark', 'NobleCoin', 'Steps', 'Synergy', 'Gambit', 'Sprouts', 'SecretCoin', 'ZiftrCOIN', 'Titcoin', 'Bitcredits', 'FoldingCoin', 'UFO Coin', 'SOILcoin', 'bitBTC', 'Adzcoin', 'CryptCoin', 'DopeCoin', 'Sling', 'Nyancoin', 'Karmacoin', 'GenesysCoin', 'MangoCoinz', 'AmsterdamCoin', 'PopularCoin', 'Einsteinium', 'LimeCoinX', 'Influxcoin', 'Prime-XI', 'Bata', '8Bit', 'PayCon', 'HunterCoin', 'ExclusiveCoin', 'Bitz', 'ReturnCoin', 'QuazarCoin', 'Blakecoin', 'Grantcoin', 'NeosCoin', 'GCoin', 'Genstake', 'bitGold', 'MonetaryUnit', 'PrimeChain', 'Axiom', 'Neutron', 'KhanCoin', 'bitSilver', 'Sapience AIFX', 'SwagBucks', 'CrownCoin', 'AntiBitcoin', 'Droidz', 'Bitzeny', 'SongCoin', 'Bantam', 'MindCoin', 'BREAKcoin', 'CryptoCircuits', 'Photon', 'Cryptographic Anomaly', 'MasterTraderCoin', 'Swing', 'Datacoin', 'GraniteCoin', 'SydPak', 'Guncoin', 'IvugeoCoin', 'Floz', 'TAGRcoin', 'IslaCoin', 'Cerium', 'UCoin', 'Unitus', 'Alexium', 'FreedomCoin', 'bitEUR', 'World Trade Funds', 'GamerholicCoin', 'RhinoCoin', '1337', 'TRMB', 'Ixcoin', 'CoinoUSD', 'BlockShares', 'SolarFarm', 'SkyNET', 'Nas', 'Pangea Poker', 'FIMKrypto', 'sharkfund0', 'CzechCrownCoin', 'Dimecoin', 'Blocknet', 'Colossuscoin V2', 'FreeMarket', 'MMNXT', 'Deutsche eMark', 'Bitstar', 'Carboncoin', 'PinkCoin', 'The Viral Exchange', 'Bottlecaps', 'Freicoin', 'Dogeparty', 'Nexus', 'Privatebet', 'NXTprivacy', 'Nxttycoin', 'Sexcoin', 'LiteDoge', 'Librexcoin', 'CryptoBuck', 'Sonic', 'NobleNXT', 'USDe', 'MMBTCD', 'CarpeDiemCoin', 'Woodshares', 'Ratecoin', 'Extremecoin', 'Yacoin', 'UltraCoin', 'FlutterCoin', 'Colossuscoin', 'BitBar', 'Sync', 'Buongiorno Caffe', '42 Coin', 'Chancecoin', 'Pandacoin', 'microCoin', 'DeBuNe', 'NeoDICE', 'LottoCoin', 'MaryJane', 'Trollcoin', 'FlappyCoin', 'HTMLCOIN', 'Viral', 'Dashcoin', 'Fibre', 'ContinuumCoin', 'MGW', 'BattleCoin', 'Sembro Token', 'RabbitCoin', 'ECCoin', 'Coin2.1', 'NoirShares', 'KoreCoin', 'CommunityCoin', 'BBQCoin', 'Philosopher Stones', 'Fastcoin', 'Pesetacoin', 'TeslaCoin', 'Sterlingcoin', 'SuperCoin', 'Piggycoin', 'TittieCoin', 'Particle', 'ApexCoin', 'IncaKoin', 'BitcoinTX', 'Emerald Crypto', 'MetalCoin', 'KeyCoin', 'Triangles', 'GlobalCoin', 'Fantomcoin', 'Uro', 'Mineralscoin', 'ParkByte', 'SmartCoin', 'NXTInspect', 'Franko', 'LiteBar', 'Jay', 'BlueCoin', 'Ringo', 'Sphere', 'Marscoin', 'Kobocoin', 'UnbreakableCoin', 'Kittehcoin', 'Aricoin', 'ClearingHouse', 'SHACoin', 'FreshCoin', 'GAIA', 'PLNcoin', '020LondonCoin', 'GrandCoin', 'BunnyCoin', 'Murraycoin', 'Animecoin', 'GlobalBoost-Y', 'Bitcoin Plus', 'Argentum', 'Nakas', 'Neutrino', 'CoolCoin', 'SatoshiMadness', 'Elacoin', 'LeafCoin', 'Heavycoin', 'Fractalcoin', 'DayTraderCoin', 'XxXcoin', 'HempCoin', 'SPEC', 'AsicCoin', 'LitecoinDark', 'Lightspeed', 'SaffronCoin', 'MultiWalletCoin', 'Helleniccoin', 'Sativacoin', 'HamRadioCoin', 'NewYorkCoin', 'FujiCoin', 'Electron', 'DeltaCredits', 'Moin', 'Libertycoin', 'Moneta', 'AeroMe', 'Tigercoin', 'Pakcoin', 'Quicksilver', 'Phoenixcoin', 'GoldPieces', 'Luckycoin', 'X-Coin', 'ChipCoin', 'CageCoin', 'Crave', 'SpainCoin', 'CorgiCoin', 'Krugercoin', 'Copperlark', 'Quotient', 'Bitgem', 'Razor', 'StrongHands', 'Aiden', 'GiveCoin', 'KlondikeCoin', 'IcebergCoin', 'CAPTcoin', 'Saturn2Coin', 'Bitcoin Scrypt', 'Positron', 'DarkCash', 'TorCoin', 'iCash', 'GoldReserve', 'RonPaulCoin', 'Viorcoin', 'Spots', 'MonetaVerde', 'RussiaCoin', 'Vcoin', 'CacheCoin', 'GreenBacks', 'StableCoin', 'BetaCoin', 'CraigsCoin', 'RosCoin', 'Joulecoin', 'TurboStake', 'Mincoin', 'Cypher', 'DarkShibe', 'Catcoin', 'Halcyon', 'Guerillacoin', 'Acoin', 'Checkcoin', 'LimitedCoin', 'Zedcoin', 'PetroDollar', 'Greencoin', 'ShieldCoin', 'Doubloons', 'Money', 'Cashcoin', 'Lycancoin', 'CandyCoin', 'ZimStake', 'FireFlyCoin', 'BellaCoin', 'Benjamins', 'Aliencoin', 'Conspiracycoin', 'Execoin', 'RotoCoin', 'CrackCoin', 'Gapcoin', 'Judgecoin', 'BeaverCoin', 'Lyrabar', 'Solecoin', 'Kumacoin', 'Glyph', 'BatCoin', 'SoonCoin', 'PreminePlus', 'Munne', 'Coven', 'Full Integrity Coin', 'MapCoin', 'TopCoin', 'ConcealCoin', 'Guarany', 'Universal Currency', 'Junkcoin', 'Umbrella-LTC', 'XCash', 'UtilityCoin', 'Bloodcoin', 'PseudoCash', 'ShadeCoin', 'Nimbus', 'OpenSourcecoin', 'Dibbits', 'Axron', 'CAIx', 'BitCrystal', '007Coin', 'Vidio', 'BitQuark', 'MazeCoin', 'Heisenberg', 'Coinaid', 'RipoffCoin', 'Quarkbar', 'AnarchistsPrime', 'ARbit', 'Hirocoin', 'DarkTron', 'Isracoin', 'Metal Music Coin', 'Dobbscoin', 'TakCoin', 'BitStake', 'Graffiti', 'CRTCoin', 'Paycoin', 'BowsCoin', 'UniCoin', 'Dirac', 'Solcoin', 'ParallelCoin', 'DarkCoin', 'Digital Credits', 'VegasCoin', 'Elektron', 'TenneT', 'Phalanx', 'Selfiecoin', 'Neocoin', 'Bubble', 'Noirbits', 'Quedos', 'Vibranium', 'Cryptokenz', 'FistBump', 'Evotion', 'ORObit', 'Save and Gain', 'GuccioneCoin', 'Digit', 'ProsperCoin', 'CryptoSpots', 'Lightcoin', 'DigitalPrice', 'SpaceCoin', 'ChainCoin', 'Hundredcoin', 'Crypto', 'P7Coin', 'Eurocoin', 'HazMatCoin', 'LegendaryCoin', 'HeelCoin', 'CryptBit', 'Fantom', 'Donationcoin', 'Denarius', 'TacoCoin', 'Unrealcoin', 'CleverCoin', 'OsmiumCoin', 'GoodCoin', 'Ozziecoin', 'Californium', '23 Skidoo', 'Forevercoin', 'DuckDuckCoin', 'GBCGoldCoin', 'BanxShares', 'Augur', 'CryptoByte', 'NuBits', 'NxttyACCI', 'Asset Backed Coin', 'ClubCoin', 'LEOcoin', 'Agoras Tokens', 'KolschCoin', 'Sharkcoin', 'UNCoin', 'BnB Coin', 'FutCoin', 'Kcoin', 'ShellPay', 'Faucetcoin', 'Stakerush', 'vTorrent', 'AIB', 'BitSeeds', 'DigiEuro', 'SpikesPrivateCoin', 'Nocturna', 'InvisibleCoin', 'SmartChips', 'Shift', 'Bytecoin', 'ROXcoin', 'Coinworkscoin', 'Pebblecoin', 'SkullBuzz', 'CraftCoin', 'PLAY', 'Local Family Owned', 'AmeroX', 'CHNCoin', 'IrishCoin', 'Motocoin', 'Aegis', 'Bolivarcoin', 'Nibble', 'BitCent', 'DarkToken', 'Cthulhu Offerings', 'BitcoinFast', 'SSVCoin', 'TickCoin', 'Diggits', 'PlanetCoin', 'Flaxscript', 'FriendshipCoin 2', 'AlphaCoin', 'AvatarCoin', 'Dubstep', 'Grexit', 'EZCoin', 'DarkCypher', 'RubleBit', 'AmericanCoin', 'AdderalCoin', 'NXE', 'Dotcoin', 'NanoToken', 'Skeincoin', 'TrickyCoin', 'Graviton', 'ElephantCoin', 'LiteStarCoin', 'X2', 'BigCoin', 'StarCoin', 'Memecoin', 'QuitDough', 'UPcoin', 'WorldPay', 'Coin(O)', 'iBits', 'Cashme', 'Trinity', 'Moneta', 'GameCoin', 'PurePOS', 'DarkEther', 'XenCoin', 'Biebercoin', 'The Cypherfunks', 'Paccoin', 'Pennies']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there - you need to use an XPath expression to select all the currency names and then store them in an appropriate variable (I use a list):

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

currencies = [curr for curr in tree.xpath('//td[contains(@class, "currency-name")]/a/text()')]
print(currencies)
```

**Output**

```
['Bitcoin', 'Ripple', 'Litecoin', 'Ethereum', 'Dash',....]
```

(I have truncated the output).

The XPath expression `//td[contains(@class, "currency-name")]/a/text()` looks for all `td` elements that have the class `currency-name`, and then returns the text from the anchor element child of the `td` element.